# What is wrong about subprocess.Popen.terminate in Python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I want to run and close explorer on Windows10 in Python script. But I can not.
subprocess.Popen.terminate() does not close explorer. What is wrong?

```
import subprocess
 
folder = r'C:\Users\issy\Documents'
pidcheck = 'tasklist | find "explorer"'
subprocess.check_output(pidcheck, shell=True)

Out[6]: b'explorer.exe 18568 Console 3 148,416 K\r\n'

Popen_explorer = subprocess.Popen(['explorer',folder])
Popen_explorer.pid

Out[8]: 2176
 
subprocess.check_output(pidcheck, shell=True)

Out[9]: b'explorer.exe 18568 Console 3 150,416 K\r\n explorer.exe 11732 Console 3 64,696 K\r\n'
# pid is different. 11732 is true. subprocess.Popen.pid shows wrong id 2176.

Popen_explorer.terminate()
# explorer does not close.
```

Comment: Windows is not like Linux. A parent process does not necessarily retain control of it's children. I don't know if this is the particular issue in your case, but when Popen() asks Windows OS to open explorer.exe; there is no guarantee that Windows doesn't start explorer.exe as a child of Windows OS and detaches it from your Popen().

Comment: Also, if it's already running, perhaps the new process just sends a signal to the existing process to open a new window, and then quits.